# Why are there no suggestions (artificial intelligence) for posting your question in the right place?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I think there should be something on the community sites themselves to suggest on  which community your question belongs.

Because I have a question and i have posted it over 4 communities, without any result.

Comment: If you mean the question you’ve recently asked on PCG (where you mention you previously asked it in Puzzling), I’m afraid an AI won’t help you. Finding the right site isn’t the principal problem with that question. The principal problem is it’s very unclear, and when you do finally get the gist of what you’re looking for, it boils down to “can you guys write this code [or equation] for me?”. That doesn’t go over well on any SE site. I do note that you mention `x%8` and so on, which is a good start, but not enough. You have to make a more comprehensive attempt to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: You should write one- there's a long tradition of community projects and I'm sure it can be done in 6-8 weeks...

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't sure where a question belongs, you can ask for a site recommendation here on MSE. Just tag the question with [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation).

We don't have any artificial intelligence for this yet, it seems like a pretty complex project to build. Especially since Stack Exchange sites aren't static, their scope changes over time - usually the scope becomes more narrow. Also, sometimes specific sites split off.

Then again, we have some very creative bot builders in the chatrooms, so maybe some of them would like to pick up the challenge. It's a pretty big AI challenge, that's for sure. Don't expect anyone to build this quickly; it involves NLP and understanding what's being asked in the question.

Keep in mind that some things are off-topic on every Stack Exchange site. For example, polls ("what is your favorite x") are simply not a good fit for the Stack Exchange model.

Comment: Thanks, but posting a question to post another not a good idea!, i mean if i need to post a question and not sure where to post it, i have to post question on meta and wait for answer then post it on the right community.

Comment: @android We have a tag _specifically for this purpose_. Just, when you use it, give as much information about the question you intend to ask. The more we know about the question you want to ask, the better we can help you find the appropriate SE site.

Comment: @android: Like most other question types, you don't have to actually *ask* a [tag:site-recommendation] question to benefit. Make sure to search well first, and perhaps you won't have to post a question at all.

Answer (score 0):

### In theory, great, let’s have it!

### In practice, maybe not...

Think of it this way: If an automated process is able to understand from question body and question title what the OP wants to know (and hence can redirect OP to the best site on the SE network), the system itself becomes obsolete because duplicate flags could be handled automatically, not-an-answer flags could be handled automatically etc.

Furthermore, scopes of site are not something constant and are sometimes not represented by questions asked on the site (sub-aspects are underrepresented and might get ignored by the algorithm, or some questions might just not get closed as off-topic because of a lack of attention).

The lesser amount of off-topic questions asked by users on the wrong sites because of themselves will be mitigated by the amount of off-topic questions asked by users on the wrong sites because of this algorithm.

This will likely lead to Scope-Wars<sup>TM</sup> (*But the System recommended me to post here, why are you closing it then*) and, as a result, in confusion about site scopes and even more [site-suggestion](/questions/tagged/site-suggestion) questions.

Basically the algorithm would just move the problem from unknowing users to faults in the algorithm itself. And it’s always easier to teach users than to constantly fix the algorithm.